# $id = $_GET['id'] : variable is not working

Tags: php, include, get

I am trying to send email by
1) Using $_GET['id'] to define the mysql row
2) Extract the relevant info from the database, including the email address and 
3) Send email to the extracted email address.

No errors are reported with error reporting on (note that pasted code has them commented out), but the variables below ($street2 and $email) don't seem to be retained via the include file. The echo's all work fine when they are not commented out. When I replace the $email variable (on the include file, not shown) with an actual email address, everything sends fine.

I think the main thing to note is in Line 9, if I define the $id, then everything works fine. However, if I try to use $_GET to define the $id variable, then the echoed variables still show up fine (meaning the db queries are successful), but the include file doesn't work.

Here is my code. It is placed above the HTML form. I've included some comments within the code so you can have a better idea of what has worked or not.

```
<?php
session_start() or die("Could not start session.");

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$id = 0;
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
//$id=4;
//if Line 9 is not commented out, then the whole script works fine and email is sent
require('connect.php');

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT street2 FROM prop_one WHERE sellerID='$id'") or die("OOPS: Bad    query1");
$row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1, MYSQL_NUM);
$street2 = $row1[0];
//echo "This is $street2";

$query2=mysql_query("SELECT email FROM account WHERE sellerID='$id'") or die("OOPS: Bad query2");
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2, MYSQL_NUM);
$email = $row2[0];
//echo "<br>This is $email";

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
include_once("emailSeller_inc.php");
}
?>
```

Here is the form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" name="emailToSeller">
<fieldset>
  <legend>Your Contact Info
  </legend>
  <label for="conFName">First name*</label>
  <input name="conFName" type="text" id="conFName" value="<?php echo stripslashes(htmlentities($conFName)) ?>" placeholder="required" required = "required" size="35" maxlength="50"/>
<label for="conLName">Last name</label>
<input name="conLName" type="text" id="conLName" value="<?php echo stripslashes(htmlentities($conLName)) ?>" size="35" maxlength="50"/>
<label for="conEmail">Email*</label>
<input name="conEmail" type="email" id="conEmail" value="<?php echo stripslashes(htmlentities($conEmail)) ?>" placeholder="required" required="required" size="35" maxlength="50"/>
<label for="conTel">Phone</label>
    <input name="conTel" type="text" id="conTel" value="<?php echo stripslashes(htmlentities($conTel)) ?>" placeholder="" size="25" maxlength="15"/>&nbsp;e.g., 555.555.5555
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="text-align: center; position: absolute; top: -200; z-index: -1000;">
<input class="teaser" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Your Message
  </legend>
  <label for="conSubject">Subject*</label>
  <input name="conSubject" type="text" id="conSubject" value="<?php echo stripslashes(htmlentities($conSubject)) ?>" placeholder="required" required="required" size="35" maxlength="50"/>
  <label for="conMessage">Message*</label>
  <textarea name="conMessage" type="textarea" id="conMessage" placeholder="required" required="required" cols="50" rows="8" maxlength="400"/><?php echo stripslashes(htmlentities($conMessage)) ?></textarea>

  <label class="teaser">Email</label>
  <input class="teaser" name="validate" id="validate" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="text-align: center">
  <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send email"/>
</fieldset>
   </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: What happen for echo $_GET['id'] ?

Comment: try is_int instead of is_numeric otherwise sth like "4e12a" would be valid, too

Comment: where is connect.php? is in correct path? Maybe you can activate display errors from php.ini (or check the logs) to see the error given by php

Comment: scalopus: If I echo the $id, or $_GET['id'], it echoes out just as it should. In other words, when the URL says ?id=4, the echoes show me 4. Thanks!

Comment: do a `print_r($_REQUEST);` and paste the output in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the id from `$_GET`, then later checking the `$_POST` for 'submit'.  What is the method on your form? My guess is your method is POST.

You can either try echo'ing out `$_GET['id']` before line 9 like scalopus mentioned in comments, or try switching it to `$_POST['id']`.

**edit**

Add the hidden field for id to the form as mentioned in comments. The else die at the bottom is optional and you can remove it once you are sure things are working as you expect.  You dont need to wrap the include in the `isset($_POST['submit'])` any more - if the id is set, then submit is too.  Hope this helps.

```
    <?php
    session_start() or die("Could not start session.");

    $id = 0;
    $email = null;
    $street2 = null;

    if(isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id']))
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        require('connect.php');

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT po.street2, a.email FROM prop_one po JOIN account a ON po.sellerId = a.sellerId WHERE sellerID = '$id' LIMIT 1") or die("OOPS: Bad query " . mysql_error() );
        list( $street2, $email ) = mysql_fetch_row($query);

        //echo "Street2 is $street2";
        //echo "<br>Email is $email";

        include_once("emailSeller_inc.php");
    }
    else
    {
       die( 'no Id set in Post');
    }
?>
```

Comment: If not sure on method, he can use $_REQUEST instead.

Comment: KMFK: If I echo out $_GET['id'], it echoes out the number just fine. Thanks for the POST suggestion. I tried redefining $id = $_POST['id'] and still the script fails to send. And yes, I am using POST as the form sending method. Is that why GET isn't working to define the $id? Thanks for your input!

Comment: scalopus: How would I use $_REQUEST and why do you think that might solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Maggie - is the Id a field in the form, or is it in the query string ( in the url )?  Can you edit your question to include the form html as well.

Comment: KMFK: The id comes from the URL via GET. The id is NOT a field in the form. Do I need to put id into a field in the form (hidden presumably) for it to get recognized properly via $_POST? I'll post the form as you suggest if needed--was trying to keep it short! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you would need it in the form.  The Id is in the url when you request the form page, but the form is now doing a POST request ( I assume to itself ).  The query string parameters are not being passed again in that request.  I would create a hidden field and add the id to it.  Change your `$_GET['id']` to `$_POST['id']` and you should be ok - editing my answer with some some cleaned up code for you.

Comment: OK, so this problem seems to have been due to my lack of understanding about the difference between GET and POST. KMFK's suggestion sounds logical. I'll revise my code as suggested by KMFK and will report back!

Comment: Excellent! Using a hidden field to send the $id worked! I actually kept the $_GET['id'] on Line 8, but in the form I added a hidden field so that the included script can generate $postID = $_POST['postID']. I also moved the mysql queries into the include file. Thanks to KMFK for sending me in the right direction! PS Tried to vote you up but I'm too much of a noob :-)